# How to change multiple column values in R?

Tags: r

I am trying to change some specific values in a column from 0 to 1 using dplyr. I'm working with a state park dataset and created a binary column (Swimming) for whether it has a beach / swimming.

The code below is what I've tried so far:

```
data.frame %>% mutate(Swimming = replace(Swimming, Park == c("Park1", "Park4", "Park8"), 1))
```

The code changed Park1$Swimming from 0 to 1, but not the other parks. This is a simplified version of the dataset; there are closer to 30 parks I'm trying to change the swimming column for. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You want `%in%`, not `==` for this. `==` tests pairwise equality. With R's "recycling" of vectors, `Park == c("Park1", "Park4", "Park8")` tests if `Park[1] == "Park1"`, then `Park[2] == "Park4"`, then `Park[3] == "Park8"`, then `Park[4] == "Park1"`, etc.

Comment: There's a FAQ for this somewhere, but it's hard to find...

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks a lot for the response.

Answer (score 0):

## data input

I'm not sure how your `dataframe` looks but if all you want to do is change a specific column's value from 0 to 1 for certain parks you can simply do as follows. Please post a reproducible example next time

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- data_frame(
  park = paste0("park", 1:4),
  swimming = c(0,1,0,1)
)

df %>%  
  mutate(swimming = if_else(park  %in%  c("park2", "park3"), if_else(swimming == 0, 1, swimming), swimming))
#> # A tibble: 4 x 2
#>   park  swimming
#>   <chr>    <dbl>
#> 1 park1       0.
#> 2 park2       1.
#> 3 park3       1.
#> 4 park4       1.
``
```